# Google Analytics analytics.js - Enhanced Ecommerce

Tags: google-analytics, google-analytics-api

I am using https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/analyticsjs/enhanced-ecommerce

to add enhanced analytics tracking to my application . When I am trying to add impression I got following error in the console in analytics console

**VM17923 analytics_debug.js:10 Command ignored. Plugin "ec" has already been required on tracker "t0".**

Can anyone help please ! I am using ga('require', 'ec') to register this plugin and when i removed it it tells me plugin not registered .
I also tried giving name to the trackor but not worked well

Comment: Is `ga('require', 'ec')`be run twice? Can you reproduce this on a simple web page? See [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: Hello Matt , thanks for your reply . They were called two times in my page. Now there is no error but i am not able too my product impression in Analytics account however my command are executing properly

Comment: Here is reference for my page - https://www.screencast.com/t/y3S04msdA 
And here is my report which seems empty - https://www.screencast.com/t/q0SALBn9zC . Ecommerce setting are enabled